# Finding what data type a user inputted string is?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently stuck on an exercise from my courses. It's our "extra work" so I expected it to be a bit more challenging but our automatic checking system gives me only 80/100 points and idk where my code breaks.

The goal of the exercise is for a user to input strings until they give the command "END". For each string we check what variable it is. So if user inputed "1.25" we print out "1.25 is floating point type variable.", etc. Here's my code. I basically put out a bunch of TryParse statements in a while loop if you don't really wanna read the whole of it.

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;
namespace ExtraExercises
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = string.Empty;
            while (input != "END")
            {
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input == "END")
                {
                    break;
                }
                BigInteger num;
                decimal dec;
                bool myBool;
                char myChar;

                if (bool.TryParse(input, out myBool) == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{input} is boolean type");
                }
                else if (BigInteger.TryParse(input, out num) == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{input} is integer type");
                }
                else if (decimal.TryParse(input, out dec) == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{input} is floating point type");
                }

                else if (char.TryParse(input, out myChar) == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{input} is character type");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{input} is string type");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you covered all of the necessary types? Also you could simplify the `char.TryParse` code to simply `input.Length == 1`, since that's basically the same thing.

Comment: I tried it out with input.length == 1 but it gave me 60/100 for some reason and yes, I have covered all character types. I'm really scratching my head at this since theoretically it should work 100% of the time

Comment: I wonder if they expect you to use `int.TryParse` rather than `BigInteger.TryParse`, and are giving you a lower score for allowing numbers that are too big?

Comment: Does auto-checking system checks code quality somehow? If so, the reason could be in chained `if... else`.